# Append array in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

I have initialized array like this declared in my FirstViewController class:

```
var List = [
WebAn(name: "CPH 1", latitude: 55.751465, longitude: 12.580909, url: "https://www.test1.com"),
WebAn(name: "CPH 2", latitude: 45.566558, longitude: 12.682434, url: "https://www.test2.com")]
```

And later on my FirstViewController I want to add ad object to the list array, but using this code I don't see any result (I am printing the array in the console):

```
self.List += [WebAn(name: "CPH 3", latitude: 55.867037, longitude: 12.386092, url: "https://www.test3.com")]
```

I am still learning Swift and Xcode, and I can't figure out where I am wrong.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Unrelated, but Swift convention recommends to write properties lowercase: so `self.list` instead of `self.List`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am trying in playground and it adds new object to the array when I add below code out of class scope.

```
WebAn(name: "CPH 1", latitude: 55.751465, longitude: 12.580909, url: "https://www.test1.com"),
WebAn(name: "CPH 2", latitude: 45.566558, longitude: 12.682434, url: "https://www.test2.com")]
List += [WebAn(name: "CPH 3", latitude: 55.867037, longitude: 12.386092, url: "https://www.test3.com")]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
list.append(WebAn(name: "CPH 3", latitude: 55.867037, longitude: 12.386092, url: "https://www.test3.com"))
```

This will add the item to the array.